# Vertex-connectivity of a not complete graph

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple, not complete graph. I'm asked to prove that:

$$\kappa(G)\geq2\delta(G)-|V(G)|+2$$

where $\kappa(G)$ is the vertex-connectivity of $G$, $\delta(G)$ is the minimum degree of $G$ and $V(G)$ is the set of all the vertices of $G$.

Any tips on how to start would be really appreciated.

Comment: It might be helpful to assume $2\delta(G) - |V(G)| + 2 \ge 1$ (the statement is trivial otherwise), so you get $\delta(G) \ge \frac{1}{2}(|V(G)| - 1)$.

Comment: @DoughnutPump I have an answer but I didn't use your suggestion. Did you have another solution in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have a solution, I guess I'd better update this.

Let $S$ be a vertex cut set of $G$ such that $|S| = \kappa(G)$ and let $G_{min}$ be the component of $G-S$ with the least number of vertices. Then, 
$$|V(G_{min})|\leq\frac{|V(G)| - |S|}{\omega(G-S)}\leq\frac{|V(G)| - |S|}{2}\tag{1}$$
Where $\omega(G-S)$ is the number of components of $G-S$.
Suppose a vertex $x\in V(G_{min})$. Then,
$$|S|+|V(G_{min})|-1\geq d_{G}(x)\geq\delta(G)\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we have
$$|S|+\frac{|V(G)|-|S|}{2}-1\geq\delta(G)$$
And since $|S|=\kappa(G)$
$$\kappa(G)\geq2\delta(G)-|V(G)|+2$$